# What is the derivative of function respective to it's integral?

Tags: derivatives, euler-lagrange-equation

To make the notation here more readable I transposed it all down one derivative, so the question I'm having is what is this:

$$
\frac{d \frac{d f(b)}{d b}}{d f(a)}
$$

The question came up while I was trying to derive the wave equation from the Lagrangian (from what I read on the internet, this is not how one's supposed to be doing it, but I'm not a physics student but a hobbyist who's doing it for fun, so if I want to hit my head against a rock I'm going to do it), so it's actually the square (but this shouldn't change anything):

$$
\frac{d \left(\frac{d f(b)}{d b}\right)^2}{d f(a)}
$$

Wolfram Alpha says both are zero and a manual derivation from the definition of the derivative says the same, but – assuming I didn't do something wrong – it *has* to be $\ne 0$.

Edit:

For a bit of context, I was trying to derive the wave equation
$$
a \frac{d^2 V}{d^2 t} + b \frac{d^2 V}{d^2 x} = 0
$$
from – what I believe to be the appropriate – Lagrangian (on the internet the Lagrangian is usually formulated with tools of general relativity or something, which I don't fully understand):
$$
L = \frac{1}{2} m \frac{d V}{d t}^2 - \frac{1}{2} k \frac{d V}{d x}^2
$$
Applying now the Euler-Lagrange equation
$$
\frac{d L}{d q} = \frac{d}{d t} \frac{d L}{d \dot{q}}
$$
causes me to have to evaluate the asked about expression (just with $V$ instead of $f$).

Comment: I don't understand what this is supposed to mean.

Comment: @Randall In what regard?  If you're confused by the text, just ignore it.  If my maths isn't completely bad, the formula should be a completely well formed expression.  Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm also confused by what you wrote. Can you provide more context or where the expression came from? I think you're trying to do some variational calculus.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I added a bit of context.  Hope that helps!

Comment: One can only take a derivative with respect to a variable, and $f(a)$ is not a variable.

Comment: What is $\frac {df(b)}b?$

Comment: @RossMillikan That was a typo.  I fixed it now.

Comment: @GregMartin That is totally possible.  It's not taught in school, but it's very frequent in higher math (this is coincidentally also of course the reason why I'm struggling with that).  Just look at the Euler-Lagrange equation (which I copied verbatim from Wikipedia), it is taken respective to $q$, which is shorthand for $q(t)$ – a function.

Comment: Putting $df$ in the denominator can be sensible, but you have to make sure you've been clear about what depends on what. Putting $df(a)$ in the denominator? Something's not right.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC To be honest, I'm not quite understanding that, but would it be solvable if I would leave the $(a)$ out or if it were changed to $(b)$?

Comment: I doubt it. I'm not great at mathematical physics, but generally $q$ and $\dot q$ represent generalized position and velocity quantities, and the energy and Lagrangian are functions of them. $V$ looks to be playing the role of some kind of energy, so you shouldn't be differentiating wrt it. I'd suggest understanding $V$ better first.

Comment: Though I see you've accepted an answer, you also might want to go ask the underlying question on the physics SE.

Comment: @ErnestBredar: You seem to have misunderstood. When forming the Euler–Lagrange equation, you take the usual partial derivatives of the function $L(q,v,t)$ with respect to the *variables* $q$ and $v$, not with respect to any functions. *Afterwards*, you substitute the functions $q=q(t)$ and $v=\dot q(t)$, and compute the time derivative.

Comment: @HansLundmark - the first part of your comment sounds right, but your "afterwards" part? I mean, conceptually yes, but in practice the first part leaves you with a differential equation for $q(t)$, which you then have to solve. I guess if you're curious about the time evolution of $L$ you can put your $q$ (and $v$) solution back in.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC: I just mean that notation such as $\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}(q(t),\dot q(t),t)$ means that you compute the standard partial derivative w.r.t. the variable $q$ first, and then evaluate it at a time-dependent point. When computing the partial derivative, you just have $L(q,v,t)$ where $q$ and $v$ and $t$ are independent variables, with no time-dependence for $q$ and $v$. It's a bit confusing to use the same notation $q$ for the variable and for the function (and even more confusing to write $\partial L/\partial \dot q$), but it's standard notation.

Comment: @HansLundmark - Yeah, I was just making a quibble - you explained what it means, I just wanted to outline how it tends to be used in Euler-Lagrange problems. But your explicitly writing out of the partial derivative of $L(q,v,t)$, and explaining how should be understood, would honestly make a better answer than the accepted one. If you do turn it into an answer, please "@" me so I can upvote it.

Comment: This is a great example of how notation can go bad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let The integral be F.  Then f= dF/dx and you are asking about df/dF.
By the chain rule df/dF= (df/dx)(dx/dF)= (df/dx)(1/(dF/dx))= (1/f)(df/dx).

Answer (score 0):

The expression $$\frac{d \frac{d f(b)}{d b}}{d f(a)}$$ makes absolutely no sense. It is a combination of how bad can Lebniz's notation go, intertwined with the catastrophic confusion that has people write $f(x)$ when they mean $f$ and the really bad practice of confusing a formal argument of a function with the value at which that argument is taken.

What is *meant* is probably the following. We have a function $f$ defined on some interval $I$, and it has a derivative $f'$ on that interval. The function is such that the set of points $\{(f(x),f'(x)):x\in I\}$ happens to be (part of) the graph of a funtion, that is, there exists a function $u$ such that $f'(x)=u(f(x))$ for each $x\in I$. The expression in the question is intended to denote the derivative $u'$.

Given this, the meaningless notation $$\frac{d \left(\frac{d f(b)}{d b}\right)^2}{d f(a)}$$ is probably trying to denote the derivative of the function $u^2$, and of course, neither $u$ nor $u^2$ need have zero derivative in general.

For example, let us take consider the function $f$ such that $f(x)=x^3$ for all $x>0$. Its derivative has $f'(x)=3x^2$ for all $x>0$, and therefore there is indeed a function whose graph contains the set $\{(f(x),f'(x)):x>0\}$: the function $u$ such that $u(t)=3t^{2/3}$ for all $t>2$ clearly is such that $$u(f(x))=3(x^3)^{2/3}=3x^2=f'(x)$$ for all $x>0$. In this case we have that neither $u$ nor $u^2$ have zero derivative, of course.